# Adding newline in chat automatically transforms message into a code block

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat

If you hit <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> while writing a message in Chat and continue onto the new line, when you submit your message, it will be **automatically converted into a code block**.
[image: bug + freehand circle]

Instead, it should be left as normal text.

Comment: +1 , just for being productive in the face of the chat vortex.

Comment: @Aiden if you call drawing a freehand circle productive. :)

Comment: It's obvious that the system assumes that a multi-line message is code pasted into the textarea, I don't think all browsers let you `Shift + Enter`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For info, we're experimenting with some changes to this area:

- by default, a multi-line message (or paste) is **not** treated as code (so no `<pre>`)
- if, however, **all** the lines are indented it *is* treated as code; a bit like the editor here
- with a button/keypress to automatically indent etc

This *should* give us a fairly consistent behaviour (vs SOFU/SE), while retaining the flexiblity to post both types of message

Answer (score 2):

This is completely by design, though. The typical chat message will be a single line; anything other than that should be multiple chat messages.

Comment: Still, it's tripped me up about 100% of the times I've typed a multi-line chat (admittedly, that only means 3 times). Maybe disallowing shift+enter is better in this case?

Comment: +1, I started writing an answer saying that I thought this would be by design, but demoted it to a comment instead.